# Why do I get a superfluous pip upgrade error on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip

First off, this is **NOT** the same question that's been asked many times before.
**I experience this with pip upgrade only, not with other packages.**

My *pip upgrade* actually succeeds, but I still get EnvironmentError. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**Note:** My python installation is NOT on default path (c:\Users\<usrname>\AppData\Local), it is installed under c:\Progs\Python
Here is the full text of console interaction:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

D:\>pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 547kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\<usrname>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-qkg3722a\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


D:\>pip install -U pip --user
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\progs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)
```

Comment: Maybe related (especially the part about Windows specifically): https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is a little annoying with overwriting files, that are currently opened.
so if you call `pip.exe` it will have difficulties to update `pip.exe` with a new version.
Just use

```
py -m pip install -U pip
```

instead of

```
pip install -U pip
```